Create HTML FormatNumber error Power Automate
I tried to format the HTML Table below for the number

This is the expression that I used:
formatNumber(int(item()?['Trans Amt']), '0,0.00', 'en-us')

However, it gives an error message as below.

The numbering format expectation is as follows "100,000.00"
Thank you.

Are they all int?  If not you will get this error. Try decimal(...) or float(...) as an alternative.

it works perfectly! thank you

The error expression likely due to incorrect usage of int() and formatNumber()
converting the value to an integer you should ensure your are formatting the number correctly.
like,
formatNumber(float(item()?[Trans Amt]),'0,0.00',en-us)

float(item()?[Trans Amt])  -  this converts the value to a floating-point number
formatNumber()  -  this formats the number according to the pattern '0,0.00'

it works perfectly! thank you
